# I fail to see why web services need to be uniquely identified using namespaces

Tags: xml, wcf

> Each XML Web Service needs a unique
>   namespace in order for client
>   applications to distinguish it from
>   other services on the Web.  By
>   default, ASP.Net Web Services use
>   http://tempuri.org/ for this purpose. 
>   While this suitable for XML Web
>   Services under development, published
>   services should use a unique,
>   permanent namespace. Your XML Web
>   Service should be identified by a
>   namespace that you control.  For
>   example, you can use your company's
>   Internet domain name as part of the
>   namespace.  Although many namespaces
>   look like URLs, they need not point to
>   actual resources on the Web.

I understand that XML namespaces help us uniquely identify vocabularies defined by XML Schemas. But I fail to see why web services also need to be uniquely identified using namespaces?!

Namely, for client to be able to communicate with a service, it needs to know the service’s address, binding and a contract and that’s it. So why would two different services using the same namespace cause any problems to client trying to use these two services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially correct: You get one namespace per service, so if you know the URL of the WSDL (or if you have a copy of it), the namespace is not particularly helpful. However, the namespace is permanent, whereas the WSDL is not. In services where you look up the location of the WSDL for services -- a UDDI server, for instance -- the namespace is a way to know that you're really talking about the service you're interested in.

As always, we use namespaces as an abstraction layer, so we're not dependent on the WSDL (or worse, endpoints') location to know which service we're talking about.

That said, the namespace really doesn't make much of a difference in most of our WS uses, since we use the physical location of the WSDL to figure out where the service is. You could use tempuri, but people would laugh, though the joke is really is on them.

Comment: "In services where you look up the location of the WSDL for services -- a UDDI server, for instance -- the namespace is a way to know that you're really talking about the service you're interested in." A - You mean if we only know the namespace of a service, we could search UDDI for the service that uses that namespace and UDDI would return appropriate wsdl for that service? B-So essentially the main purpose of using namespaces with services is we can use them to locate wsdl of a service we’re interested in (using UDDI server or anything that returns appropriate wsdl for particular namespace)?

Comment: @user437291 - A - yes, B - yes, and also to provide a unique identifier for the service, though it may never be used.

Comment: Sure thing. Also note the comment by @Mads Hansen, where he notes that one service may be hosted in several locations (but which share a namespace).

Answer (score 4):

> I understand that Xml namespaces help
>   us uniquely identify vocabularies
>   defined by Xml Schemas. But I fail to
>   see why web services also need to be
>   uniquely identified using namespaces?!

For the same reason.  To uniquely identify the service(s).

Services can have multiple endpoints.  If two endpoints were running the same service, the namespace helps you recognize that they are implementations of the same service.

A unique service namespace can also be used to indicate the version of a particular service.

Comment: "Services can have multiple endpoints. If two endpoints were running the same service, the namespace helps you recognize that they are implementations of the same service." Uhm, I must say I don't quite understand your argument. When you query the mex endpoint of a service, it returns wsdl specifying endpoints this service has. So I don't understand why you would need a namespace to tell you the two endpoints belong to the same service, since you figure that out when you request metadata for that service?!

Comment: The URL or location of the service does not necessarily define the service. (Web) Services can be hosted in a variety of locations and providers and be the same service. Uniquely identifying things through namespaces removes ambiguity. Yes, you could also attempt to resolve it's identity through metadata for the service, but if you had uniquely identified the service to begin with you would not have to. Also, if two different services used the same namespace, code generation tools might generate stubs that stomp on each other and have other identity/versioning conflicts.